# Display AxisRenderer outside Flex Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, graph, charts

Is there a way to display the Vertical Axis outside the graph?
I need the limits of the graph to be displayed between the vertical axis, without overlapping the series over the graph.

See that screenshot of what I have:

[AxisRenderer http://img.skitch.com/20090907-cctubueupd1b8xai55msfeyu42.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090907-cctubueupd1b8xai55msfeyu42.png)

I need to get something like:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090907-fa8q6r6mr68ps87bwh4q7bgrmq.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090907-fa8q6r6mr68ps87bwh4q7bgrmq.png)

Or I should create a custom axis renderer component that get data from this graph and display it outside?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the AxisRenderer to do this .
search the flex 3 api ,key word is "AxisRenderer "

then go to the style you will find "tickPlacement" .

the following is one example:

```
<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{verticalaxisid}" tickPlacement="outside" />
</mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
```